# Webpack minimize option breaks application if set to true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am experiencing an issue about webpack: if I set `config.optimization.minimize: false`, webpack produces not-minified bundle files (polyfills, vendor and app), then I run the server and all works fine. If I change the option to `config.optimization.minimize: false` I am getting following AngularJS (1.7.9) error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module saServer2App due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module saServer2App.account due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e


https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=saServer2App&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20saServer2App.account%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20e%0A%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.9%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DsaServer2App.account%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Aunpr%255D%2520Unknown%2520provider%253A%2520e%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.7.9%252F%2524injector%252Funpr%253Fp0%253De%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A837%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A23977%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520u%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A25576)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A25881)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.invoke%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A25969)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A25365)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A25009%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520x%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A1529)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A24869)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A24955%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520x%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A1529)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A24869)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520We%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A24189)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520i%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A10341)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.Et%2520%255Bas%2520bootstrap%255D%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fvendor.bundle.js%253A7%253A10656)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520HTMLDocument.%253Canonymous%253E%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Fapp.bundle.js%253A348%253A233259)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Flibs%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A30005)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520t%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9000%252Flibs%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A30307)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A837%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A25194%0A%20%20%20%20at%20x%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A1529)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A24869)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A24955%0A%20%20%20%20at%20x%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A1529)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A24869)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20We%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A24189)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20i%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A10341)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.Et%20%5Bas%20bootstrap%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A7%3A10656)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20HTMLDocument.%3Canonymous%3E%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fapp.bundle.js%3A348%3A233259)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Flibs%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A30005)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20t%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Flibs%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A30307)
    at vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:895
    at vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:5819
    at x (vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:1144)
    at g (vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:5779)
    at We (vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:5696)
    at i (vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:2719)
    at Object.Et [as bootstrap] (vendor.6729935a0c85787ce014.bundle.js:2740)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:74)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

This is a bit strange, especially to me that I am new in AngularJS and Webpack. The only thing I change between the two scenarios is only the `minimize` flag. What could be wrong?

Feel free to ask some portions of my files/codes I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs dependency injection is based on the function argument names.
For example:

```js
class AuthService {
  constructor(otherService) {
  // ------------^ will inject otherService
  }
}

angular.module('my-app', []).service('authService', AuthService);
```

The problem is that when you minify your code, the minifier will replace function arguments into something shorter (usually one char).
This is what happens in your case, this explains why the angular tries to inject `e` (`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e`).

In order to overcome this issue, angular supports [array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#the-array-notation) which defines the dependencies as a string.

```js
// Given
const MyController = function (obfuscatedScope, obfuscatedRoute) {
  // ...
};

// Define function dependencies
MyController['$inject'] = ['$scope', '$route'];
```

There is a webpack plugin which annotates automatically, [ng-annotate-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jeffling/ng-annotate-webpack-plugin).

It handles most of the cases, but sometime you need to help it by adding a special comment.

```js
class AuthService {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor(otherService) {
  // ------------^ will inject otherService
  }
}

angular.module('my-app', []).service('authService', AuthService);
```

If you are a babel user, check this [babel plugin](https://github.com/schmod/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate).